# How to make a triangle move and rotate using GDI in C++

Tags: c++, windows

I want to make a triangle move from one place to another then rotate it 270 degrees using Polygon() function does anyone knows how to?? Just a simple one.

Comment: Note that GDI is pretty ancient at this point. Take a look at [Direct2D](http://blogs.technet.com/b/thomasolsen/archive/2008/10/29/introducing-the-microsoft-direct2d-api.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

[`Polygon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162814(v=vs.85).aspx) takes an array of points that define the polygon; in your case this would be three points that define a triangle:

```
POINT triangle[] { {x0, y0}, {x1, y1}, {x2, y2} };
```

Define your triangle relative to some origin point that makes sense for you. For example, a triangle with the origin (roughly) in the center:

```
POINT triangle[] { {-10, -10}, {10, -10}, {0, 15} };
```

To draw this triangle at any given `x, y` point, add `x` and `y` to the appropriate component of each point:

```
POINT triangle[] { {x + -10, y - 10}, {x + 10, y - 10}, {x, y + 15} };
```

And then pass that set of points to `Polygon`. A simple function to do all of this would look like:

void DrawTriangle (HDC dc, int x, int y) {
     POINT triangle[] { {x + -10, y - 10}, {x + 10, y - 10}, {x, y + 15} };
     Polygon(dc, triangle, 3);
   }

Then, pick a starting point given by some `x, y`, and an ending point given by some other `x', y'`. Every frame add some value to each `x` and `y` (probably scaled by delta time in order to have framerate-independent movement) to move it towards the target point, and call `DrawTriangle` with that new x and y.